# Access the U.S. version of The Huffington Post

Tags: usa, united-kingdom

I moved from the U.S. to the U.K.  While in the U.S. I would frequently check the U.S. version of `The Huffington Post` for news.  Now that I am in the U.K. every time I try to access the U.S. version of that website I am automatically redirected to the U.K. version.

I have tried using different web browsers and different search engines.  Nothing I have tried has worked.  Perhaps `The Huffington Post` can remotely detect the country I am in and automatically directs me to that country's version of the site.  Or perhaps the website uses a cookie for that purpose?

How can I access the U.S. version without being in the U.S.?

Comment: Did you try accessing via a VPN to the states?

Comment: @Gagravarr I suppose I could remotely connect to a computer in the U.S. and access the internet using that computer.  I am not sure if that is what you mean.  However, that seems like a complex solution.  I am just using a computer in the U.K. right now and accessing the internet with Chrome or Explorer.  This week I obtained a laptop that runs Linux and can access the internet, but I am not familiar with that computer yet.

Comment: They detect your location based on the IP from which your request comes. That's why the VPN suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the US version of the page there's a drop-down menu titled "Edition", where you can chose which country you want it to show you. I'm from the US so it defaults to US, but I can *select* the UK version from that menu - and that's what I'll see.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same answer as littleadv but just added a graphic. Yes, you can use the `Edition` to select `United States`

[image]